# Multiple parenthetical citations from different sources mid sentence

Tags: mla, parentheticals

I'm trying to keep with MLA format 7th edition and I'm not sure how to properly parenthetically cite a complex sentence.

I have sources S1, S2, S3 where S1 and S2 have the same author, but different texts, and S3 is from a different author. The sentence looks like:

We know that [fact 1 from S1], [fact 2 from S2], and [fact 3 from S3].

I would like to write

We know that [fact 1 from S1] (S1), [fact 2 from S2] (S2), and [fact 3 from S3] (S3).

so that it is clear which reference each fact came from. However, the guides I found online say to always put parentheticals at the end of the sentence, like

We know that [fact 1 from S1], [fact 2 from S2], and [fact 3 from S3] (S1; S2; S3).

I don't like this format because it isn't clear where each fact came from, and it is further complicated by S1 and S2 having the same author.

What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://www.library.cornell.edu/resrch/citmanage/mla) site, it appears that your initial inclination is perfectly acceptable. Note specifically to the third example given.